# Aws Lambda python timed out after 20s when creating an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an `aws lambda` function to create an `s3` bucket. I have written this using `python 3.6`

Here's my code:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    return client.list_buckets()
```

And I have set the `timeout` value as `20s` and increased the memory to `512mb` as well.

I have attached `AmazonS3FullAccess` as well to the `IAM role` of lambda. But I get the following error:

> {
> "errorMessage": "2021-06-18T16:49:19.237Z 1a33460c-8d7e-45f1-8601-c5b01290e439 Task timed out after 20.02 seconds"
> }

Why am I getting this error? Can someone help me please?

Comment: can ou share your lambda code?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I have shared it in the above question

Comment: Is your lambda associated with a custom VPC (your defined VPC instead of the default managed VPC)?

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run inside a VPC? If so, it won't have access to S3 unless you have configured an S3 endpoint in the VPC, or you have configured it to run in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway.

Comment: @MarkB thanks man, you saved me

Answer (score 1):

As per the MarkB's suggestion, the issue was with the lambda function bound to a vpc. If Lambda function configured to run inside a VPC you should make sure that it has access to S3. Can be achieved by configuring an S3 endpoint in the VPC, or you have configured it to run in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway